# PHP array filter (Just like SELECT all FROM ARRAY where key1 in $ARRAY1 and key2 in $ARRAY2)

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [questionid] => 21790
            [name] => "________ would anyone hurt my poor cat?"
            [userid] => 2
            [firstname] => Admin
            [category] => 69080
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [questionid] => 21770
            [name] => Choose a suitable meaning of ‘bright’
            [userid] => 2
            [firstname] => Admin
            [category] => 69053
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [questionid] => 21769
            [name] => Choose the correct English word for: سمجھنا
            [userid] => 2
            [firstname] => Admin
            [category] => 69053
        )
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...

)
```

I want to search this array for two values `questionid` and `userid` and these values lie in arrays like:

```
$questionids = array(23434, 33232, 33321);
$userids = array(2, 6, 33, 67, 88, 22, 43);
```

In short, I want every such element from the main array whose two values (questionid and userid) lie in arrays `$questionids` and `$userids`.

I have tried many solutions but not able to figure out any optimal solution yet. Any help would be appreciated.

**from comments**

I have tried:

```
function search( $array, $key, $value ) {
  $results = array();
  if ( is_array( $array ) ) {
    if ( isset( $array[ $key ] ) && $array[ $key ] == $value ) {
      $results[] = $array;
    }
    foreach ( $array as $subarray ) {
      $results = array_merge( $results, search( $subarray, $key, $value ) );
    }
  }

  return $results;
}
```

But the problem with above solution is that it takes single key-value pair and I have multiple key-value pairs to look for (both in different arrays).

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: and did that work Ali?

Comment: It is working but doesn't fulfill my criteria. It takes single key-value pair, and I have multiple key-value pairs (and have those values in separate arrays) to look for.

Comment: Technically speaking I need something like this: 

select all from array where questionid in (implode(',', $questionids)) and userid in (implode(',', $userids))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just have a look at the function `array_filter`, which should be perfect for your needs. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php:

```
   $result = array_filter($array, "test_match", ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);

   function test_match($key, $value){
      $questionids = array(23434, 33232, 33321);
      $userids = array(2, 6, 33, 67, 88, 22, 43);

      return 
        in_array($value["userid"], $userids) && //user match?
        in_array($value["questionid"], $questionids); //question match?
   }
```

`$result` will now only contain elements that match the condition.

Note, that I read your description

> In short, I want every such element from the main array whose two values (questionid and userid) lie in arrays $questionids and $userids.

as an `and` condition. If either or needs to match, simple return

```
return 
  in_array($value["userid"], $userids) || //user match?
  in_array($value["questionid"], $questionids); //question match?
```

---

If you want to pass the parameters `$userids` and `$questionids` as parameters, you can wrap them inside an object on which you perform the callback:

See the documentation here: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php each callback supports an array (instance / method name) or just the method name as in the first example.

```
class DataClosure{
      private $qids;
      private $uids;

      function __construct($qids, $uids){
         $this->uids = $uids;
         $this->qids = $qids;
      } 

      function test_match($key, $value){
        return 
          in_array($value["userid"], $this->uids) && //user match?
          in_array($value["questionid"], $this->qids); //question match?
     }  
}
```

with the code

```
$questionids = array(23434, 33232, 33321);
$userids = array(2, 6, 33, 67, 88, 22, 43);


$result = array_filter(
   $array, 
   array(
     new DataClosure($questionids, $userids),
     "test_match"
   ), 
   ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
```

Comment: can i pass `$userids` and `$questionids` arrays to function testMatch?

Comment: I am getting this error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function arrayFilter()

Comment: @Ali because it's called `array_filter` - my bad, sry :)

Comment: Was reading you profile few minutes ago, read you are doing JAVA now a days, I guess you followed JAVA a little bit (naming convention) :D

Comment: @Ali exactly :) Note, that I also missed the `new` Keyword in front of `DataClosure(...)` as well as the `$this->` when accessing `uid` and `qid` from within `testMatch`... ehm... `test_match` :P.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89591/discussion-between-ali-and-dognose).

Comment: Hats off, That was it. All set. Thank you very much for your support. Stay blessed.

Answer (score -2):

```
$question = [];
$userid = [];

foreach($arr as $item){
     array_push($question, $item->questionid);
      array_push($userid , $item->userid);
 }
var_dump($question );
var_dump($userid);
```

updated: **navigate to your array and get the value that you want!
simple as abc!**